# Can we travel into a Schengen country with our 3-month baby, we are EU residents, she is not (yet)?

Tags: schengen, turkey, children, portugal

I am a British citizen, my wife is Turkish, we both have 5 year residencies in Portugal. My wife recently gave birth in Turkey. We will return to Portugal with our baby, who has a Turkish passport, but no Portuguese residency yet...

Will we be allowed to enter Portugal with our daughter, even if she doesn't have a valid Schengen visa.

Comment: Did you obtain your residence based on EU freedom of movement? Can she apply for a British passport?

Comment: @xngtng another question to ask: are you planning to fly to Portugal or to travel by land?